# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to hide DbContext transaction in the middleware pipeline?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building 3-tier ASP.NET Core web API. It consist of Data, Business (Core) and WebAPI layers:

1. Core layer is independent (has not knowledge of EFCore nor any other project)
2. Data layer - has reference to Core and EFCore
3. WebAPI layer - final layer, knows about Core, Data and EFCore

I was struggling making decision how to handle db transactions. I'm injecting DbContext (scoped) to my `Data` classes and well as to the Controller (I'm omitting Business project, since it doesn't know EFCore at all). Because there is only one instance of the `DbContext` per request, it's the same object in the `Data` as well as in the Controller.

So, the Business logic is doing, what's supposed to do, calling objects in the Data layer. Whenever Data layer needs to Save changes into DB, it does. Everything is wrapped around transaction per request. So if something goes wrong... all changes are rolledback.

This is sample controller's method that shows how I did it (simplified):

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult UpdateMeeting(int id, [FromBody] MeetingDto meeting)
    {
        using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            if (meeting == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _meetingService.AddMeetingChanges(meeting);

            meeting.Id = id;
            _meetingService.UpdateMeeting(meeting);
        }
        return NoContent();
    }
```

Everything works great. So what's the issue? I need to repeat this:

```
    using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {


    }
```

... in every operation, that needs transaction.

So I was thinking, is it possible to start the transaction in the middleware / pipeline (I'm not sure about terminology). Simply speaking - I want to begin transaction explicitly per EVERY request. I want to hide in the middleware. So that whenever I inject DbContext to the Data classes, there is transaction started already

**EDIT: Possible solution:**

1. Created a `UnitOfWork` class:

   ```
   public class UnitOfWork
   {
       private readonly RequestDelegate _next; 

       public UnitOfWork(RequestDelegate next)
       {
           _next = next;
       }   

       public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, MyContext ctx)
       {
           using (var transaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
           {
               await _next(httpContext);
               transaction.Commit();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Injected `UnitOfWork` class as a middleware after `UseHttpsRedirection` and before `UseMvc`:

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       }
       else
       {
           app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
           {
               appBuilder.Run(async context =>
               {
                   context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                   await context.Response.WriteAsync("An unexpected error happened. Please contact IT.");
               });
           });
       }   

       app.UseHttpsRedirection();
       app.UseMiddleware<UnitOfWork>();
       app.UseMvc();
   }
   ```

Comment: Use a middleware, inject the context, have a flag included in the request that can b einspected by the middleware to indicate that it should wrap the next in the pipeline in a transaction. Make sure the middleware is registered early enough in the pipeline .

Comment: @Nkosi thanks. To clarify, do you mean: to inject DbContext to class implementing `IAsyncActionFilter` and then add it to Mvc? like this: `services.AddMvc(options => { options.Filters.AddService<CustomActionFilter>(); }` ?

Comment: No not a filter, a custom middleware.

Comment: @Nkosi I think I got it. I edited my question with the possible answer (I didn't want to post as an answer yet). Can you confirm this is what you meant (without the flag part)?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was referring to minus checking for the flag

Comment: @Nkosi thanks. I honestly can't think of a way, how to inject a flag "whether create transaction or not" into that. Can I ask you for this one more suggestion?

Comment: I was suggesting that you include something in the request. could be a header or query sting in the URL that is present can be used as an indicator that request should be a transaction. The middle ware would inspect for the desired flag.

Comment: @Nkosi oh I see. I'm not sure if this is the good idea to ask client of the API to decide if he wants to use transaction or not. I think I'm just gonna create transaction for every request. Is it bad? I can check if the request is "GET", if it is, I'm not gonna begin transaction.

Comment: It was just a thought, not hard and fast. Using the HTTP Verb is a good idea and viable option.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and built a middleware on top of the suggestion and solution from @Ish Thomas.
And just in case somebody finds this question I want to leave my middleware solution here.

But unfortunately, I also had to use the EF Connection Resiliency configuration `EnableRetryOnFailure()`.
This configuration is not compatible with `ctx.Database.BeginTransaction()` and throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

> InvalidOperationException: The configured execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user initiated transactions. Use the execution strategy returned by 'DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()' to execute all the operations in the transaction as a retriable unit.

```
services.AddDbContext<DemoContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(
            "<connection string>",
            providerOptions => providerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure()));
```

The middleware creates a transaction when the HTTP verb is POST, PUT, or DELETE.
Otherwise, it invokes the next middleware without the transaction.
If an exception is thrown the transaction commit isn't executed and the changes made within this request are rolled back.

### Middleware Code:

```
public class TransactionUnitMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public TransactionUnitMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, DemoContext context)
    {
        string httpVerb = httpContext.Request.Method.ToUpper();

        if (httpVerb == "POST" || httpVerb == "PUT" || httpVerb == "DELETE")
        {
            var strategy = context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
            await strategy.ExecuteAsync<object, object>(null!, operation: async (dbctx, state, cancel) =>
            {
                // start the transaction
                await using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

                // invoke next middleware 
                await next(httpContext);

                // commit the transaction
                await transaction.CommitAsync();

                return null!;
            }, null);
        }
        else
        {
            await next(httpContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps somebody ;)